# How to get checkstyle to handle a class in java.net package?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm working on a fork of an open source project. I need to call `addURL` on an instance of `java.net.URLClassLoader` This method is protected, so I have created a utility class in the package `java.net`, and I make the call from there. No big deal, except that this gradle project uses checkstyle. CheckStyle complains:

`Import control file does not handle this package`

But I cannot see how to add the `java.net` package to the import control element.

```
<import-control pkg="com\.whatever|java\.net" regex="true">
```

Seems to be validate against the import_control_1_4.dtd, but checkstyle aborts when it reads the config file. What can I do here? I'd prefer not to completely disable checkstyle.

Comment: What do you mean by `abort`? If there is an exception please show it. My little test seems to work fine with it.

Comment: There is a very general error that checkstyle prints when it cannot read AND PROCESS the configuration file. I don't remember what it is. Anyway, if there is a problem with the config file, checkstyle stops, and does nothing further. That's what I meant by abort.

Comment: I gave up on this, because I discovered that every way I wanted to extend java.net is, or will be, a violation of one security policy or another. I bit the bullet and wrote a classloader. Annoying, but I guess it's better in the long run.